# Boolean Value is not getting updated in MERN stack due to lack of quotation marks

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mongoose, boolean

I am creating a logging web application, using *MERN* stack. All the functionalities are working perfectly, there is just one problem :  When I try and update the log, everything gets updated (Message, Technician, Date), just a ***BOOLEAN*** entity (attention) is not getting updated.

[image: Log Fields]

I tried many things, and in postman, I came to realise that - message, technician and date are submitted within ***quotation marks*** (***"message","tech_name","10/11/2001"***). Just the Boolean entity - attention is submitted without quotes (***true***).

Here is the data that is being forwarded to the API :

[image: Console Log]

As attention has a boolean datatype, it's just **true or false**, not ***"true" or "false"***

So when I used postman to submit the data, with adding *quotation marks* to the boolean value, ***it worked!***. I just don't know how to do that using MERN in the coding. Any Help would be appreciated. Here is the image of both submitting with and without quotation marks in postman.

**Submitting without Quotes**::
[image: Submitting without Quotes]

**Submitting With Quotes** ((It updated when I added quotes to false)
)::
[image: Submitting With Quotes]

I am using MERN (Mongoose, Express, React and Node). I am pasting some of the relevant codes here. Please do comment if need any other part of my code.

// Initialisation of attention

```
const [attention, setAttention] = useState(false);
```

// Method to Update the Log

```
const updLog = {
 id: current._id,
 message,
 tech,
 attention,
 date: new Date(),
 };
updateLog(updLog);
```

// Update Log Action

```
export const updateLog = (log) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    setLoading();
    const res = await fetch(`/logs/${log.id}`, {
      method: "PUT",
      body: JSON.stringify(log),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    });
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log(data);
    dispatch({
      type: UPDATE_LOG,
      payload: data,
    });

    clearCurrent();
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: LOGS_ERROR,
      payload: err.response.statusText,
    });
  }
};
```

// Back-end Update Route

```
router.put("/:_id", async (req, res) => {
  const { message, tech, attention, date } = req.body;

  const logFields = {};

  if (message) logFields.message = message;
  if (tech) logFields.tech = tech;
  if (attention) logFields.attention = attention;
  if (date) logFields.date = date;

  try {
    let log = await Logs.findById(req.params._id);

    if (!log) return res.status(404).json({ msg: "Log Not Found" });

    log = await Logs.findByIdAndUpdate(
      req.params._id,
      {
        $set: logFields,
      },
      {
        new: true,
      }
    );

    res.json(log);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send("Server Error");
  }
});
```

(Check out this to see what's happening : https://gifyu.com/image/GGi6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can of course change the client to always send the attention field as a string

```
const updLog = {
 id: current._id,
 message,
 tech,
 attention: attention ? "true" : "false",
 date: new Date(),
 };
updateLog(updLog);
```

But your real problem lies within the following line:

```
if (attention) logFields.attention = attention;
```

the `if (attention)` only evaluates to true if the attention field is set **and true** - if you just want to check if the attention field is `undefined` or `null`, compare the variable with `null` instead (which also catches when the value is undefined. [Source](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/recap/null-undefined)):

```
if (attention != null) logFields.attention = attention;
```

To test beforehand if I identified the problem correctly, try using postman to change the attention value from `false` to `true` by just passing the boolean - it should work. Just not the other way around because `logFields.attention` is never set when `attention` is not a truthy value.

Comment: Thanks a lot!... Both the solutions worked! Really Appreciate.